# Is my macbook pro x86 linux or x86_64 darwin?

Tags: x86, x86-64, platform

This might be a really dumb question, but I need to know what platform is my Macbook Pro.
I want to download a plug-in for Eclipse to code in Ada and it's asking for my platform.
I use a Macbook pro so is it x86 - linux (or) x86_64-linux (or) x86_65-darwin and also what year.
Again, this might be really stupid, but I need some help :)

So, thanks in advance for helping, guys.

Comment: click the little apple icon on your top left (and click on About This Mac)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't specify the platform. I maybe looking at it wrong

Comment: I'm pretty sure the System Profiler should tell you... /Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app

Comment: I'm going to guess darwin. That is the Apple kernel that is written on top of unix. You should be able to find it in some system application though.

Comment: I tried the System Profiler way but could not comprehend the answer.
But what did solve my query was "uname -a" and "uname -m" commands in the Terminal.

The response was: Darwin and x86_64 respectively. Darwin was in accordance to @atreat 's answer>

Answer (score 45):

If you open up your terminal and type the command `set` and press enter, you should see a long list of env variables. The MACHTYPE (usually pretty far down) should tell you what you're running.

```
MACHTYPE=x86_64-apple-darwin13
```

...is what my Macbook Air is on.

To just see that write `set | grep "MACHTYPE"`

Comment: Wouldn't `echo ${MACHTYPE}` save time finding the right line in that long list?

Comment: `set | grep MACHTYPE` works too :)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this application useful:

http://www.mactracker.ca/

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps an unorthodox solution, but works on pretty much anything...

Grab the GNU project's latest [`config.guess`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD) - this is used in *lots* of packages using the autotools build system. Simply run this shell script, and you'll get a concise cpu-vendor-os triple.